# Merge multiple queries into single one

Tags: mysql

I wish to have total users of each **role** who make differents **type_role** of actions.

This is my tables:

```
t_users : id_user, username, userpass, status, ...
t_action: id_action, id_user, id_role, id_type_role, ...
t_role: id_role, libelle, status
t_type_role: id_type_role, libelle, status
```

This is my datas:

```sql
INSERT INTO `t_users` (`id_user`, `username`, `password`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'foo', 'pass1', '1'),
(2, 'bar', 'pass2', '0'),
(3, 'fusion', 'pass3', '2');

INSERT INTO `t_role` (`id_role`, `libelle`, `statut`) VALUES
(1, 'Operator', 1),
(2, 'User', 1),
(5, 'Administrator', 1);

INSERT INTO `t_type_role` (`id_type_role`, `libelle`, `statut`) VALUES
(1, 'Executif', 1),
(2, 'home', 1),
(3, 'System', 1);

INSERT INTO `t_action` (`id_action`, `id_user`, `id_role`, `id_type_role`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5, 3),
(2, 2, 5, 3);
```

**Expected result:**

| ROLE | Executif | home | System |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Administrator | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| Operator | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User | 0 | 0 | 0 |

For each **role**, COUNT **Users** who have make actions WITH EACH column **Type_of_role** :

this is my queries written on each cell:

| ROLE | Type_role_1 | Type_role_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DISTINCT(t_role.libelle) **role_1** | SELECT count(U.id) **Type_role_1** FROM t_users U JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user=U.id JOIN t_type_role TR ON TR.id=A.type_role JOIN t_role R ON R.id=A.id_role WHERE R.libelle= **role_1** AND TR.libelle= **Type_role_2** | SELECT count(U.id) **Type_role_1** FROM t_users U JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user=U.id JOIN t_type_role TR ON TR.id=A.type_role JOIN t_role R ON R.id=A.id_role WHERE R.libelle= **role_1** AND TR.libelle= **Type_role_2** |
| DISTINCT(t_role.libelle) **role_2** | SELECT count(U.id) **Type_role_1** FROM t_users U JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user=U.id JOIN t_type_role TR ON TR.id=A.type_role JOIN t_role R ON R.id=A.id_role WHERE R.libelle= **role_2** AND TR.libelle= **Type_role_1** | SELECT count(U.id) **Type_role_2** FROM t_users U JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user=U.id JOIN t_type_role TR ON TR.id=A.type_role JOIN t_role R ON R.id=A.id_role WHERE R.libelle= **role_2** AND TR.libelle= **Type_role_2** |

Please, help

Comment: we, or at least me, cannot understand your goal here, would you mind posting further details with a sample of the wanted output.

Comment: please show what you have tried; are you having trouble figuring out how to join your tables?  how to aggregate?  or just the conditional aggregation part?  https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+conditional+aggregation

Comment: i have edit my post now. So you could see at bottom side, an example of de result i expect

Comment: again, please show what you have tried and explain what part you are having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry. I have rewrite my post. It's more explain now. And, as i've wrote, i want to have one query which could retrieve this statement.

Comment: @ysth  According to your first post, i found a great course [here](https://www.sobstel.dev/blog/conditional-aggregate-functions-magic-in-mysql/) .
So i'm now able to write the single query like edited on my question above<br/>
Thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **First solution**:
  As suggested by another user on comment, i've write the single query like this one:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  R.libelle ROLE,  
  COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Executif', 1, NULL )) AS Executif,
  COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Home', 1, NULL )) AS Home,
  COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'System', 1, NULL )) AS System
FROM t_users U
JOIN t_action A ON A.id_user = U.id_user
JOIN t_role R ON R.id_role = A.id_role
JOIN t_type_role T ON T.id_type_role = A.id_type_role
GROUP BY ROLE
```

it works fine.
But how about add another **COUNT conditions** dynamically?

**Update**: 
this **conditions** should have to be built dynamically. Because, they are based on the table T.libelle wich could grow on time. 
**example**: If we add a new value to T.libelle, the query should have to include this new value on query accoding to the syntax of CONDITIONS... 
Below, 
`CONDITIONS = COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Executif', 1, NULL )) AS Executif,` 
             `COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Home', 1, NULL )) AS Home,` 
             `COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'System', 1, NULL )) AS System`

So, if we add an entry **new_libelle** to T.libelle, CONDITIONS should become
`CONDITIONS = COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Executif', 1, NULL )) AS Executif,` 
             `COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'Home', 1, NULL )) AS Home,` 
             `COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'System', 1, NULL )) AS System` 
             `COUNT( IF( T.libelle= 'New_libelle', 1, NULL )) AS New_libelle`

Comment: USING SUM and CASE WHEN

Comment: @TaurusSilver , this conditions should have to be built dynamically. Beacause, they are based on the table T.libelle wich could grow on time. example:
If we add a new value to T.libelle, the query should have to include this new value on query accoding to the CONDITIONS... some ideas ?

Comment: there's no good way to add conditions dynamically.  either find the values you want columns for and build the sql in the client, or build an sql select query in a string and use prepare/execute sql commands.

Comment: @ysth , okay. I'm on way to build it on sql command. But, is it possible to construct this CONDITIONS and send it to mysql as parameter ?

Comment: um, it just makes up part of the select; how you sending the select to mysql?

Comment: @ysth , i'm on php. So i use PDO (prepare/execute) commands to send queries to MySQL.